# Can we scan Azure PAAS services in Qualys? And which module does it used

Tags: security, scanning, qualys

Unable to find much content of PAAS services scan in qulays.So kindly help to find if Qualys has any specific module for vulnerability scanning on Azure PAAS services.
Qualys official website doesn't have much information on PAAS